# Update selected option dynamically when filter is applied?

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I have two forms, each with a select field and some options. The first form works as a filter for the second, but when I select something in the first form, the second form updates fine, but the selected option remains, even though it's been filtered out. How to I fix this? Tried with the option:first-child approach, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my code so far (I'm really, REALLY new to jQuery)

```
<form action="select.php" method="post">
    <select name="color" id="color">
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="purple">Purple</option>
        <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    </select>
</form>

<form action="select.php" method="post">    
    <select name="character" id="character">
        <option value="leo" class="blue">Leo</option>
        <option value="smurf" class="blue">Smurf</option>
        <option value="thedevil" class="red">The Devil</option>
        <option value="raphael" class="red">Raphael</option>
        <option value="donnatello" class="purple">Donnatello</option>
        <option value="mike" class="orange">Mike</option>
    </select>   
</form>

<script>
    $('#color').change(function() {
        var myColor = $('#color option:selected').val();
        $('#character option').hide();
        $('#character option').filter("." + myColor).show();
        $('#character option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");
    });    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the value of the `#character` select to the first `option` that matches the filter, not the first child within the select as that never changes. Try this:

```
$('#color').change(function() {
    var myColor = $('#color').val();
    $('#character option').hide().filter("." + myColor).show().first().prop("selected", true);
}).change();
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/9976zj8x/)